# Not all EC2 instances can be retrieved, only a one-third of it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Here is the simple script to get all ec2 instances and their ebs data for particular instance type, and script extracts around 100 instances data not the entire instances(~350)

assume_role_and_create_session -> as the name assume role

get_ec2_instances -> Get all the ec2 instances with filters instance type as c6g.xlarge and r6g.xlarge, keyName - prod-or and in running state

get_ebs_data -> Get the EBS Volumes and check the attached resource matches with the instance extracted post filter

write_csv_file -> write the extracted data into csv file as per need

```
import boto3
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def assume_role_and_create_session(tmp_session, role_arn):
    sts_connection = tmp_session.client('sts')
    assume_role_object = sts_connection.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName="GetEBSData", DurationSeconds=900)
    
    return boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=assume_role_object['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=assume_role_object['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=assume_role_object['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    )

def get_ec2_instances(session, instance_types, keyName):
    ec2_client = session.client('ec2', region_name=region_name)
    instances_data = []
    next_token = None
    
    while True:
        if next_token:
            response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
                Filters=[
                    {
                        'Name': 'instance-type',
                        'Values': instance_types
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'key-name',
                        'Values': [keyName]
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                        'Values': ['running']
                    }
                ],
                NextToken=next_token
            )
        else:
            response = ec2_client.describe_instances(
                Filters=[
                    {
                        'Name': 'instance-type',
                        'Values': instance_types
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'key-name',
                        'Values': [keyName]
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                        'Values': ['running']
                    }
                ]
            )

        instances_data.extend(response['Reservations'])
        next_token = response.get('NextToken')

        if not next_token:
            break
        
    return instances_data

def get_ebs_data(session, instance, instance_types):
    instance_id = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceId']
    instance_key_name = instance['Instances'][0]['KeyName']
    instance_type = instance['Instances'][0]['InstanceType']
    
    if instance_type in instance_types:
        ec2_client = session.client('ec2', region_name=region_name)
        volumes_response = ec2_client.describe_volumes(
            Filters=[
                {
                    'Name': 'attachment.instance-id',
                    'Values': [instance_id]
                }
            ]
        )
        
        volumes_data = []
        
        for volume in volumes_response['Volumes']:
            volume_id = volume['VolumeId']
            volume_type = volume['VolumeType']
            volume_size = volume['Size']
            volume_iops = volume.get('Iops', 'N/A')
            volume_snapshot_id = volume.get('SnapshotId', 'N/A')
            
            volumes_data.append([instance_id, instance_key_name, instance_type, volume_id, volume_type, volume_size, volume_iops, volume_snapshot_id])
        
        return volumes_data
    else:
        return None

def write_csv_file(data, file_path, sum_volume_size):
    with open(file_path, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        
        csv_writer.writerow(['InstanceId', 'Instance KeyName', 'Instance Type', 'EBS Volume Id', 'Type of EBS', 'Size of EBS', 'IOPS', 'Volume Snapshot'])
        csv_writer.writerows(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    region_name = 'us-west-2'

    env_roles = {
        'prod': "PROD_ARN",
        'dev': "DEV_ARN"
    }

    tmp_session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",  # Replace with your access key
        aws_secret_access_key="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY",  # Replace with your secret key
    )

    env = 'prod'
    role_arn = env_roles[env]
    session = assume_role_and_create_session(tmp_session, role_arn)

    instance_types = ['c6g.xlarge', 'r6g.xlarge']
    keyName = 'prod-or'
    instances_data = get_ec2_instances(session, instance_types, keyName)

    data = []

    print(f"Number of instances obtained: {len(instances_data)}")

    for instance in instances_data:
        volumes_data = get_ebs_data(session, instance, instance_types)
        if volumes_data:
            data.extend(volumes_data)

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
    csv_file_path = f'{env}_{region_name}_{timestamp}.csv'
    write_csv_file(data, csv_file_path, sum_volume_size)
    print(f"CSV file '{csv_file_path}' created successfully.")
```

Initially, I had not added NextToken in the script, after updating script with the same the number rose from 80 to 108

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have a lot of filters on the API call. How do you know that there are 350 instances matching ALL those criteria? (Note that it will `and` the criteria, not `or`.) You could try removing the filters and instead filter the response within your code (in a list comprehension).

Comment: Even when nextToken is specified, i'm unable to get all  ec2 instances for the specified filters. With the same  AWS EC2 console, I see a number around 350. As per ur recommendation, I removed filters except for instance-type and the result was still the same.

Comment: I added print statements and found that there is no NextToken in the response, is there a better way to handle the pagination?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, your script will be a lot faster if you pull all the EBS volumes, make a dict of instance id to volume and then refer to the dict, rather than making an API call for each instance.

Comment: @erik258 Thanks for your input, will incorporate your suggestion to the script